# Fixing corrupt PNGs missing the IEND chunk

Tags: python, imagemagick, png, image-manipulation

I have `.png` files outputted by a tool that converts `.emf`s to `.png`s but that doesn't add the IEND chunk to the end.

Therefore, other tools, like ImageMagick, won't go near them as they detect them as corrupt:

```
> pngcheck test.png
test.png  file doesn't end with an IEND chunk
```

However, I can open the `.png` fine in desktop GUI image viewing applications, so my current workaround is to open it in these applications (e.g. Preview.app) and re-export the image, which then gets saved with the correct headers, etc.

This obviously isn't scale-able, and I need something to work server side in an automated way.

How do I go about fixing the images, preferably with a method that can be automated and run server-side, e.g. using Python?

[This](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/070P2R363N362J0G1p3B/test.png) is the image in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do this in Python with:

```
from PIL import Image
file_in = "test.png"

img = Image.open(file_in)

file_out = "test-fixed.png"

img.save(file_out)
```

Requires PIL/Pillow `pip install Pillow`

Comment: This thread was bumped because it doesn't have an accepted answer.  The question is written as a product request, so it is attracting close votes.  You might want to accept your own answer.